# zeromq route-req java example does not work

Tags: request, zeromq, routes, jeromq

I run this official Java example in Eclipse, with jeromq-0.3.2.jar library, it doesn't work if I "run" it, it only works if I set some break point and "debug" it.

It seems the message is lost. My own application using route-req pattern has this problem too.

This is their official example, if this doesn't work, what can? can someone try it and figure out why?

http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:rtreq

or codes are here:

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Context;
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket;

import java.util.Random;

/**
* ROUTER-TO-REQ example
*/
public class rtreq
{
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    private static final int NBR_WORKERS = 10;

    private static class Worker extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
            Socket worker = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
            ZHelper.setId (worker);  //  Set a printable identity

            worker.connect("tcp://localhost:5671");

            int total = 0;
            while (true) {
                //  Tell the broker we're ready for work
                worker.send ("Hi Boss");

                //  Get workload from broker, until finished
                String workload = worker.recvStr ();
                boolean finished = workload.equals ("Fired!");
                if (finished) {
                    System.out.printf ("Completed: %d tasks\n", total);
                    break;
                }
                total++;

                //  Do some random work
                try {
                    Thread.sleep (rand.nextInt (500) + 1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            worker.close();
            context.term();
        }
    }

    /**
     * While this example runs in a single process, that is just to make
     * it easier to start and stop the example. Each thread has its own
     * context and conceptually acts as a separate process.
     */
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
        Socket broker = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
        broker.bind("tcp://*:5671");

        for (int workerNbr = 0; workerNbr < NBR_WORKERS; workerNbr++)
        {
            Thread worker = new Worker ();
            worker.start ();
        }

        //  Run for five seconds and then tell workers to end
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis () + 5000;
        int workersFired = 0;
        while (true) {
            //  Next message gives us least recently used worker
            String identity = broker.recvStr ();
            broker.sendMore (identity);
            broker.recvStr ();     //  Envelope delimiter
            broker.recvStr ();     //  Response from worker
            broker.sendMore ("");

            //  Encourage workers until it's time to fire them
            if (System.currentTimeMillis () < endTime)
                broker.send ("Work harder");
            else {
                broker.send ("Fired!");
                if (++workersFired == NBR_WORKERS)
                    break;
            }
        }

        broker.close();
        context.term();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this example works, you need to be sure that each worker has unique id.

As an example, I removed

```
ZHelper.setId (worker);  //  Set a printable identity
```

and add a constructor to Worker class with workerId string.

Result:

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * ROUTER-TO-REQ example
 */
public class rtreq {
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    private static final int NBR_WORKERS = 10;

    private static class Worker extends Thread {

        private String workerId;

        Worker(String workerId) {
            this.workerId = workerId;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
            ZMQ.Socket worker = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
            worker.setIdentity(workerId.getBytes());

            worker.connect("tcp://localhost:5671");

            int total = 0;
            while (true) {
                //  Tell the broker we're ready for work
                worker.send("Hi Boss");

                //  Get workload from broker, until finished
                String workload = worker.recvStr();
                boolean finished = workload.equals("Fired!");
                if (finished) {
                    System.out.printf(workerId + " completed: %d tasks\n", total);
                    break;
                }
                total++;

                //  Do some random work
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(rand.nextInt(500) + 1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

            worker.close();
            context.term();
        }
    }

    /**
     * While this example runs in a single process, that is just to make
     * it easier to start and stop the example. Each thread has its own
     * context and conceptually acts as a separate process.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
        ZMQ.Socket broker = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
        broker.bind("tcp://*:5671");

        // starting all workers
        for (int workerNbr = 0; workerNbr < NBR_WORKERS; workerNbr++) {
            Thread worker = new Worker("worker-" + workerNbr);
            worker.start();
        }

        //  Run for five seconds and then tell workers to end
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
        int workersFired = 0;
        while (true) {
            //  Next message gives us least recently used worker
            String identity = broker.recvStr();
            broker.sendMore(identity);
            broker.recvStr();     //  Envelope delimiter
            broker.recvStr();     //  Response from worker
            broker.sendMore("");

            //  Encourage workers until it's time to fire them
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime)
                broker.send("Work harder");
            else {
                broker.send("Fired!");
                if (++workersFired == NBR_WORKERS)
                    break;
            }
        }

        broker.close();
        context.term();
    }
}
```

System out:

```
worker-2 completed: 27 tasks
worker-3 completed: 20 tasks
worker-8 completed: 24 tasks
worker-6 completed: 23 tasks
worker-0 completed: 20 tasks
worker-9 completed: 21 tasks
worker-7 completed: 20 tasks
worker-5 completed: 21 tasks
worker-4 completed: 19 tasks
worker-1 completed: 25 tasks
```